# Finding time complexity of my solution to the 'longest palindrome' problem in Python

Tags: python, complexity, palindrome

Here is a short version!

```
def longestPalindrome(string):

    # Will use this string to record the longest palindrome seen so far
    largestPalindrome = ""

    for index in range(0, len(string)):

        reqcharMatch = string[index]

        # Since a palindrome must have matching start and end characters
        # I will find the index of all occurrences of the current 
        # character that I'm looking at in the remaining string.

        # Will accomplish this using regular expression or simply
        # by passing the character I'm looking to find, the remaining 
        # string to another function, it will return a list having 
        # indices where matching character is present.

        # Let us for example assume that, the character I'm at currently
        # is also present in indices 4, 8, 9. 
        # otheroccurList = [4, 8, 9]

        otheroccurList = regexFunctionHere()

        for occurrenceIndex in range(len(otheroccurList)):

            originalString = string[index: otheroccurList[occurrenceIndex] + 1]

            reversedString = originalString[::-1]

            # If the string obtained by slicing from the current 
            # character to the next occurence of the same character is 
            # a palindrome, and the length of this particular string is 
            # more than the largestPalindrome seen so far, then update 
            # largestPalindrome to be equal to the current Palindrome 
            # we are looking at.

            if((reversedString == originalString) and (len(originalString) >= largestPalindrome)):

                largestPalindrome = originalString


    # If literally no palindrome is found, then simply return the
    # first character in the string
    if largestPalindrome == "":
       return string[0]

    else:
       return largestPalindrome
```

Here is a longer version, please forgive me if its not refactored. I did my best to ensure good variable names, but you can copy paste this and run it with whatever test cases, it will pass them.

Long version:

```
class Solution:

    @staticmethod
    def findallOccurrence(findcharIndex, chartoFind, remString):

        """
        Function to find the all other indices where a character
        appears.
        """

        occurrenceList = []

        for i in range(len(remString)):

            if(remString[i] == chartoFind):


                index = findcharIndex + i + 1

                occurrenceList.append(index)
                index = 0

        return occurrenceList

    @staticmethod
    def reverseString(origString):
        """
        Function to reverse a string
        """

        return origString[::-1]

    @staticmethod
    def checkPalindrome(origString, reversedString):

        """
        Function to check if the original string and the reversed 
        string is a palindrome.
        """

        if(origString == reversedString):
            return True

        else:
            return False

    def longestPalindrome(self, A):

        """
        This is my main function whose short version I've explained.
        """

        longestPalindrome = ""

        for index in range(len(A)):

            findChar = A[index]

            remainingString = A[index + 1:]

            oList = findallOccurrence(index, findChar, remainingString)

            for j in range(len(oList)):

                origString = A[index: oList[j] + 1]
                revString = reverseString(origString)

                isPalindrome = checkPalindrome(origString, revString)

                if(isPalindrome == True) and (len(origString) >= len(longestPalindrome)):

                    longestPalindrome = origString

        if(longestPalindrome == ""):
            return A[0]

        else:
            return longestPalindrome


sol1 = Solution()
sol1.longestPalindrome("abaaaaaa")
```

The reason I'm having trouble finding the time complexity of my solution is that there are many interlinked loops, and different function calls within them.. I think its O(n^2), but it looks like its O(n^3).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! When you have two versions of a program, as here, we'd prefer you to pick the one you think is best. (Reviewing two versions is more than twice the work, so you'll get better answers with just one version.)

Comment: I might be wrong but i think the reverse string function is raising it to n^3 since you are doing an O(n) every n^2

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts on the long version only:

1. Use at least one linter like `pycodestyle` on your code to learn to write more idiomatic Python. This makes the code easier to read for other Python developers.
2. Most of the names are good (`longestPalindrome`), but

   1. `index`, `i` and `findcharIndex` in a single method is very confusing,
   2. the semantics of `A`, `oList`, `j` and `Solution` all have to be inferred from context which is mentally taxing, and
   3. type suffixes like in `remString` are generally discouraged.
3. `if foo then return true else return false` should be replaced with simply `return foo` in any language.
4. Ideally your algorithm should not need the `if(longestPalindrome == ""):` check at the end - `longestPalindrome` should contain the longest palindrome by then.
5. Many `@staticmethod`s is a common anti-pattern indicating that the code is really imperative rather than object oriented. This code might work better as a `@property` of `str`, since semantically that is what it is.